# TvarRec and release the memory in delphi

Tags: delphi, memory-management

I'm trying to dublicate record in DataSet.

```
procedure TMSExtQuery.CloneCurRecord(IgnoreFields: array of const);
begin
  AppendRecord(RecordFieldsValue(IgnoreFields));
end;

function TMSExtQuery.RecordFieldsValue(IgnoreFields: array of const): TFieldsArray;
var
  Idx: integer;
  V: Variant;
begin
  SetLength(Result, FieldCount);
  for Idx := 0 to Pred(FieldCount) do
  begin
    if not FieldInArray(Fields[Idx], IgnoreFields) then
      Result[Idx] := VarToVarRec(Fields[Idx].Value)
    else
      Result[Idx] := VarToVarRec(Null);
  end;
end;

function VarToVarRec(const AInput: Variant): TVarRec;
begin
  New(Result.VVariant);
  Result.VType := vtVariant;
  Result.VVariant^ := AInput;
end;
```

When I'm creating a dynamic variable I must to release the memory allocated for it.
For example:

```
function VarToVarRec(const AInput: Variant): TVarRec;
var
  V: PVariant;
begin
  New(V);
  V^ := AInput;
  Result.VType := vtVariant;
  Result.VVariant := V;
  Dispose(V);
end;
```

When i do

```
New(Result.VVariant);
```

Must I release the memory too, or it does Delphi?

Answer (score 2):

You must release it. TVarRec is a type that is meant to be used *only* as parameter, and is usually managed by the runtime, but **only if the runtime allocated and filled it**, in the form of an `array of const`. Otherwise it is up to you to manage them.

More here, in an article I wrote about it (at the end there is code to manage TVarRecs:) [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Answer (score 1):

Rudy, thanks for link. I have read and did so

```
procedure TMSExtQuery.RecordFieldsValue(IgnoreFields: array of const; out Result: TFieldsArray);
var
  Idx: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, FieldCount);
  for Idx := 0 to Pred(FieldCount) do
  begin
    New(Result[Idx].VVariant);
    Result[Idx].VType := vtVariant;
    if not FieldInArray(Fields[Idx], IgnoreFields) then
      Result[Idx].VVariant^ := Fields[Idx].Value
    else
      Result[Idx].VVariant^ := Null;
  end;
end;

procedure TMSExtQuery.CloneCurRecord(IgnoreFields: array of const);
var
  Args: TFieldsArray;
begin
  RecordFieldsValue(IgnoreFields, Args);
  AppendRecord(Args);
  FinalizeVarRecArray(Args);
end;

procedure TMSExtQuery.FinalizeVarRecArray(var Arr: TFieldsArray);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    Dispose(Arr[I].VVariant);
  Arr := nil;
end;
```